# Dart send array of object to api

Tags: api, dart

I trying to send array of object to laravel api but I can't do that I trying but get response error sayed products
"must be an array"
any one help me?
This is my code

"products":[{
product:95,
quantity:6
}],

This is my laravel post request
[Image of request example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63NPK.jpg)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add the code you are using to send the query from Dart ?